# ASP.NET MVC5 Dockerized throws COMException when Bundling with Razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, docker, razor, dockerfile

We are trying to dockerize our ASP.NET MVC5 app and got the following error at Line 9. We ran into the same issue before when dealing with bundling, but this time with docker we are not sure if it's a problem on the project side or caused by missing dependency in dockerfile. The dockerfile is straightforward and only uses `FROM microsoft/aspnet` as the base image.

The Web API part of our application is working well, but none of the page content would render past this first bundled css asset. The sources files are published using VS17 publish to file system with pre-compiling toggled on.

```
Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A1390
...

Line 7:      <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
Line 8:      @RenderSection("styles", required: false)
Line 9:      @Styles.Render("~/Content/css") 
Line 10:     @Styles.Render("~/Content/cssstylesheets") 
Line 11:     @Styles.Render("~/Content/Select")
--
Source File: C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Views\Shared\_LoginLayout.cshtml    Line: 9
```

Has anyone seen the same issue before? Thanks!

Comment: For anyone interested in this issue, I've posted the same question to [github](https://github.com/Microsoft/aspnet-docker/issues/51)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After many hours of research, I believe it's most likely caused by the fact that there is no docker support with IE so bundle transformer couldn't work. For more info, here is a more detailed discussion with a solution: https://github.com/Taritsyn/BundleTransformer/issues/7